# Typescript conditional type

Tags: typescript

So I have a problem with a conditional typing, it's the first time I've used it so I've made a [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOTYIgZxmiQBo4BvcuOAMXqQAjFAyT9GzIgBUAnmCQNW5AL60cefAAEi6GAFoAdihjAAbkj10iw0QHorCyUjKVw0eCgCuMABZrcBNrE+kYm5pYCNki2Xr4u5DBySHAAqqJQcAC8nNxwaMZIAObQwAoAXHAoBjIA2gC6pHC2tnAAFKLwzJXVcF1EACaeaMmCADYQxnDABnBIAB4o4KNIAJS5PsBM0DIVVbUNuYIQEADWIChQJwy71fUUyhTNcAAKOGAMs3PyGEj9cIIyOAAdygKDA8j+aFwkAMSAMMHI82oHgYMgMaFonnRJggM0KSBgAGFPFAiPC0kgoAAeKSfGBw-ofI4QZZVAB8rVy-WMKAA8gZRjs4FIlCsKq9cJskFTcrT5vSDIzelBPEhcjwAPypdLquAVcRCERiARbaRJBgAOgAIhA0J4QHCYABlIzvHwQGAynje70GqIG01IWTyS02u0O+FWnm6nhs8hsnI8KEGJhwTzpZCYLKVIEoYBYE1OVprH0WqGjZYYYC41r4dOUhj4Evei39W2tWI+YtlklkmAUqAai2eYD9Zs8C34mDFig8YBZ1rcmB8gUyFaJ71EGAkmb1qCZ1s84uVD4D2dwZS5Lc7tMZpCYe7kJ9I9x5XGpqcDwkFYpQUofbIRDRDFj0yBMuCTd94AYV0GHdeBANzfM4CnYlSUdAdWhgFVVnPa8oBmGCwTgj0h3yelf3-e4KCAA) but I'll paste the snippet here too:

```
import React from 'react';
import firestore, {
  FirebaseFirestoreTypes,
} from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

type User = {
  categories: any[]; // (set to any to reduce bloat in example)
  history: any[];
  bookmarks: any[];
};
// Props expected by wrapped component
export async function getCurrentUser<T extends boolean>(
  dataOnly: T,
): Promise<
  T extends true
    ? User
    : FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<
        FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData
      >
> {
  const userRef = await firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(auth().currentUser?.uid)
    .get();
  if (dataOnly) {
    return userRef.data() as User;
  }
  return userRef;
}


export const getUserCategories = async () => {
  const snapshot = await getCurrentUser(true);
  return snapshot?.categories;
};
```

What I'm hoping to have is that because I'm calling `getCurrentUser` with `true`, it infers that the return type is User, if you hover over line 34 in the playground (`return snapshot?.categories`) this is correctly inferred, and the document snapshot is inferred if I were to pass false to getCurrentUser, the problem is that I get an error on the return lines (line 26 and 28) `Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? User : DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.(2322)` and `Type 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? User : DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.(2322)` - I've messed around trying different ways of returning it etc. is there any way to set this up? (Edit: just to note, I tried returning just  `Promise<User | FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData>>` or not returning but then it doesn't narrow down the typing, I just want to see if I can get the compiler to do the narrowing rather than having to manually check after what type I got returned.)
Thanks!

Comment: No, the compiler cannot reason much about unspecified generic type parameters, especially not conditional types that depend on them.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) around this problem.  For now all you can really do is a type assertion like `as any` or `as any as Promise<...✂...>` and move on.

Comment: @jcalz ah fair enough, I'd seen a similar issue that I was alluding I might not be entirely wrong and it just wasn't possible, thanks for the comment helping confirm :)